# How can I add the stdout from a command to an hash array?

Tags: powershell

How can I add the stdout from a command to an hash array?

I want to build a PS custom object from several command results. This is possible in the following way.

```
[hashtable]$props = @{}
$tmp = & $ImageInfo -Name $fileName
$props.Add('Name', $tmp)
$info = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
```

Since there are name members to add I would like to skip the assignment to the `$tmp` variable. But I failed to make an one-line for that. How is this possible?

This gives an 'missing expression error':

```
$props.Add('Name', & $ImageInfo -Name $fileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use the hashtable::Add method. The value can also be added with an assignment:

```
$props.'Name' = & $ImageInfo -Name $fileName
```

This performs the command defined in $ImageInfo and the stdout content gets in the value of the key `Name`.

Comment: If you want to use `.Add()` you need to put the command in a grouping expression: `$props.Add('Name', (& $ImageInfo -Name $fileName))`.